# understanding uniform distribution on multiset

Tags: uniform-distribution, multisets

If I have a set of words that form a text, say text $a$, and a set of texts, I then calculate the similarity between text $a$ and each text in the set. Then, I get a multiset.

For example:

$$s = \{2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6\}$$

How can I uniformly distribute it?

What I actually want is to randomly select from this multiset, but I don't know how to deal with the multiset and to form it.

Comment: do you want to choose elements of $"s"$ randomly (uniformly) ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to take from s randomly (uniformly)

Comment: do you want an answer in terms of algorithm, or simulation like matlab ?

Comment: I don't know a lot about matlab. Maybe algorithm would be better, actually anything better and clearer would work for me. I will program it later once I understand it,

Comment: you need to generate a random discrete random variable between[1-8], which they are distributed uniformly.

Comment: why is it between 1 and 8? not 1 and 7 for example? is there a rule to define the total length? and what did you mean by generate random discrete? s could contain fraction numbers

Comment: before anything, I want to know how much do you know about the random variables since it seems you have no idea about the random variables. If so I strongly recommend you search about the elementary definitions of Random variables

Comment: I know a little about it, it is the outcome of random process. For example, when flipping a coin, a random variable can take a value if head appears and other value if tail appears.